# Maintain local variable value between calls in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Function MethodOne(ByVal s As String) As String

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    sb.Append(s)
    sb.Append(MethodTwo())

    return sb.ToString()

End Function

Public Function MethodTwo() As String

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For index As Integer = 0 To 5
        i = index
    Next

    return i.ToString()

End Function
```

I want to retain the value of i, but once it goes back into MethodOne, it loses its value.  I tried making it `static i As integer = 0`, but this did not work.

Comment: As soon as MethodTwo returns a value then i goes out of scope, setting it as Static should 'remember' the value next time you go into MethodTwo

Comment: I tried setting i as Static, but that did not work.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're asking. Your method essentially sets i to the value of 5 (your for loop is useless), so whether you retain the value or not, it will always be set to 5 again?

Comment: Is this method inside a class? If so then if you dispose of the class then the static variable is also disposed. We need to see some more code with the static inserted to find the issue.

Comment: In fact, making it `Static` **will** work. Please be more precise about your problem: “does not work” is not an accurate description.

Comment: I will post actual code.

Comment: @Xaisoft … and it would have been *so much better* if you had **not** posted the actual code, but instead a *minimal code* that exhibits the problem. Now you’re forcing us to wade through boatloads of irrelevant code.

Comment: @Konrad, but I am not quite sure what the problem could be. I could reduce the code, but then I am thinking I might take out something that could be causing the problem.

Comment: "[...] adultCount and ChildCount are still 0.". Once you're out of the method, adultCount and childCount are out of scope, so why would you care about their value?

Comment: @Konrad, if it helps, the first method called, just builds a table and at the end, it appends to the string builder what is returned from the second method (the method that contains adultCount and childCount)

Comment: @Meta-Knight, because once I am done, I send am e-mail and the e-mail contains 0 for adult and child, but I want it to show the actual values

Comment: @Xaisoft: If you need the values of adultCount and childCount outside of your method, just declare them as class members. A static variable as I showed in my answer is only useful if you want to access the variable inside that method only.

Comment: @Meta-Knight, I thought about that, but is that the only solution.  I though global variables where not good.

Comment: Unless this code is inside a Module, the variables won't be global, they will be tied to an instance of your class.

Comment: @Meta-Knight - I declared them at the top of the class, but I still got 0 for both.

Comment: I declared it as Dim adultCount As String = "0" though. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Xaisoft Well, just remove code until the problem no longer occurs, then add as much code back as is necessary to reproduce the problem. This is *the* essential debugging technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry misread that. How about creating a property called Count, and update it whenever MethodTwo is called. You can use the Property Count in MethodTwo instead of i.

```
Public Function MethodOne(ByVal s As String) As String

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    sb.Append(s)
    sb.Append(MethodTwo())

    return sb.ToString()

End Function

Public Property Count As Integer
'Count will be zero when initialized

Public Function MethodTwo() As String

    'Dim i As Integer = 0

    For index As Integer = 0 To 5
        Count = Count + index
    Next

    return Count.ToString()

End Function
```

Comment: Are you basically trying to get a running total. So if MethodTwo was called twice.. the value you want to have for i would be 10?

Comment: Well, it is a bit more complicated than that. My actual method actually returns a html table that is built with a string builder.  In the html table, I am displaying the value of i.  When I go back to method two, i no longer has the value of 10 for example

Comment: if you create a property then you should be able to store whatever value you want to retain. This will work as long as your not reinstantiating the class where this object lives.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example which is a bit different than yours (adds 5 to i instead of setting a value of 5)

```
Public Function MethodOne(ByVal s As String) As String

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    sb.Append(s)
    sb.Append(MethodTwo())

    return sb.ToString()

End Function

Public Function MethodTwo() As String

    Static i As Integer = 0

    i+=5

    return i.ToString()

End Function
```

Now, on the first run i will be set to its static value, which is 0. It will be incremented by 5, so the value will be 5. On the second one, the value of i is still 5, and it will be incremented by 5. The new value will be 10.

In your example, i was always set to 5, so it didn't change anything if you retained the value or not.

**Edit after question changed:**

What you want to do is have a class member, not a method variable. If the value is still 0 once the method has run, then there are two possible reasons for this. Either:

1. The variable is never set (AgeQualifyingCode is never 8 or 10)
2. The variable is set to 0 inside the method.

You can find out what is happening with some debugging with breakpoints.